# Laravel 5.1.4 Entrust set up

Tags: laravel-5, roles

I have problems with setting up entrust with L5..1.4

this is what i do:

```
/*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class,
```

and this: ....

```
'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Entrust'   => Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::class,
```

And its not working ... crashes my whole php artisan (when i run php artisan):

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()
```

i used this to install entrust:

```
"zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
```

and then composer update. Now EntrustServiceProvider is under vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/entrust/ ...

any ideas?

Comment: You can run the composer dump-autoload and try again.

Answer (score 2):

After adding

```
"zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
```

to your composer.json file run:

```
composer install
```

Next in the config\app.php add to the providers array:

```
'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider',
```

and under the aliases array add:

```
'Entrust' => 'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade',
```

next run:

```
php artisan entrust:migration
```

this will generate the Entrust migration and finally run the migrations:

```
php artisan migrate
```

you should now be on your way! For more information check out:
https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust